# The parameterized query '(@Educator_ID nvarchar(4000),@Subject_ID ....' expects the parameter '@Educator_ID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, wcf

**WCF CODE**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public string AdminAssign(AssignEducator edInfo)
    {
        string text = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|NoBrainerDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [EdSubject] (Educator_ID,Subject_ID,ES_Grade,ES_Subject ) values (@Educator_ID,@Subject_ID,@ES_Grade,@ES_Subject);", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Educator_ID", edInfo.Educator_ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject_ID", edInfo.Subject_ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ES_Grade", edInfo.ES_Grade);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ES_Subject", edInfo.ES_Subject);
        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            text = "User is registered ";
        }
        else
        {
            text = "User is not registered";
        }
        con.Close();
        return text;
    }
}
```

**C# Code**

```
public partial class AdminAssignEducator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client objServiceClientobjService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AssignEducator assignEd = new AssignEducator();
        assignEd.ES_Grade = Grade.SelectedValue;
        assignEd.ES_Subject = Subject.SelectedValue;
        assignEd.Subject_ID = Request.QueryString["Subject_ID"];
        assignEd.Educator_ID = Request.QueryString["Educator_ID"];
        string result = objServiceClientobjService.AdminAssign(assignEd);
        Response.Redirect("AdminAssignEducator.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it actually set in the AssignEducator?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306818/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied unless more details are added. TLDR: you don't have an `Educator_ID` in your query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually a problem with `null`. If `Educator_ID` is a type that could be `null` (`string`, `int?`, etc), then you would need to use:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Educator_ID",
    (object)edInfo.Educator_ID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Or some other code that substitutes `null` with `DBNull`. Basically, input parameters with a `.Value` of `null` *are not sent*. Alternatively, just use a framework that does this for you. Most ORMs and micro-ORMs will get this right automatically.